# Tips when drawing a large molecule using chemfig?

Tags: chemfig

I am trying to draw a large molecule using the `chemfig` package. In this case I made a figure for cobalamin variants. I somehow managed to write this code spending hours over it, but find that subsequent management to be a nightmare.

Dear chemists using TeX, please have a look at my code and tell me how to try writing it better. I have tried certain indentation styles, but nothing suitable seems to emerge.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
% More defined colors
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\chemname{
\chemfig{
*6(N-[,0.1,,,-latex] Co^{2+}(-[:90]\textbf{X})-[,0.1,,,latex-]
    N*5(=(-[:-60,,,,shorten >=14.25pt])-(<:[:20]-[:50]-[:-10](=[:-70]O)-[:50]N)-
        (<:[:90])(-[:45]-[:90](=[:-210]O)-[:35]N)
    -)
-=(-)-*5(-(<:-[:160]-[:110](=[:50]O)-[:160]N)
    -(<:[:210])(-[:120]-[:170](=[:-120]O)-[:140]N)-
    (<:[:220])*5(-*5(-(-[::-45]-[::30](=[:-210]O)-[::35]N)-
    (<:[:180])(-[:260]-[::-60]-[::60](=[::70]O)-[::-60]N-[::60]-[::60](<[::45])-[:-90]O-[:-45]P(-[::-110]O^{-})(=[::-45]O)-[:-30]O-[::60]
            *5(-(<:-[::30]OH)-O-(-\textbf{Y}(-[:94,,,,shorten >=-145pt]))-(<HO)-))
    -*6(=(-)-*5(-(<:[::-40]-[::50]-[::-50](=[::-70]O)-[::50]N)-(-[:30])(-[:-30])-(=[:70,,,,shorten >=11.5pt])-)
        =
            (N-[:130]))-)-N-[,0.1,,,-latex])
        -[,,,,shorten >=5pt])
=)}}{Basic structure}
\end{document}
```

The corresponding output looks like this where again, the bonds seem to spill into the N atom. I wish there was a way where we could convert SMILES or other such formats into chemfig formulae.

[image: Test_image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

start with the central cobalt atom and add the pentagonal rings. use the \charge command to add the 2+ charge to the cobalt.

[image]

[image]

Add the links between the pentagonal rings using long distance links (?[a], etc)

[image]

[image]

Add branches around this center ring

[image]

[image]

Add the big branch at the bottom of the molecule

[image]

Add X and the Co---Y bond (?[z]---?[z])

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
    \chemfig{\charge{30=${\scriptstyle 2+}$}{Co}?[z](-[2]X)(-[:135,,,,,dashed]N*5(-(=^[,.65]?[a](-[2]))-(<:[:90]-[:150]-[:90](=[:150]O)-[:30]NH_2)-(<[:150]-[:210](=[6]O)-[:150]H_2N)(<:[:210])-(?[d](<:[:210]))-))(-[:45,,,,,dashed,shorten <=4pt]N*5(-(=^[,.65]?[b](-[:350]))-(<:[:30]-[:330]-[:30](=[2]O)-[:330]NH_2)-(<[:30]-[2](=[:150]O)-[:30]NH_2)(<:[:120])-(?[a])=))(-[:315,,,,,dashed]N*5(-(=^[,.65]?[c](-[6]))-(<:[6]-[:330]-[:30](-[:60]NH_2)=[:330]O)-(<[:330])(<:[:30])-(?[b])=))(-[:225,,,,,dashed]N*5(-(?[d](<[4]H))-(<[:210]-[:150](=[2]O)-[:210]H_2N)-(<:[:240]-[6]-[:210](=[:150]O)-[6]NH-[:210,,1]-[6](<:[:210])-[:330]O-[6]P(<:[:150]\charge{150:2pt=$-$}{O})(=[:240]O)-[:330]O-[:30]*5((<:[6]H)-(<:[6]-[:330]OH)(<[:330]H)-O-(<:[:30]H)(<[:120]Y?[z,,,,,dashed])-(<:[2]H)(<[:150]HO)))(<[:300])-(?[c])=))}
\end{document}
```

[image]